# Using a one model to populate the dropdown for the view on another model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I've been striking out on how to handle this situation.  I have a model, the project model, and it has numerous items that need to be dropdowns for the user to change the selected item in question.  I started out simple with the ProjectType value, which should have the selectable values populated form the ProjectTypes table.  Here is the ViewModel:

```
    public class ProjectViewModel
{

    public APT_Projects Project { get; set; }
    public System.Linq.IQueryable<APT_ProjectTypes> projecttypes { get; set; }
    public APT_ClientTypes ClientTypes {get; set;}

}
```

Here is the controller:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {



        APT_Projects apt_projects = db.APT_Projects.Find(id);
        if (apt_projects == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ProjectViewModel Project = new ProjectViewModel();

        var apt_projecttypes = from a in db.APT_ProjectTypes
                                            select a;


        Project.Project = apt_projects;
        Project.projecttypes = apt_projecttypes;

        return View(Project);
    }
```

and finally the view:

```
@model APTII_MVC.ViewModel.ProjectViewModel 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<fieldset>
    <legend>APT_Projects</legend>

    <div class="editor-label" style="float: left; width: 500px;"  >
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.Project_ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" style="float: left; width: 500px;" >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project.Project_ID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.Project_ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label"">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.ProjectType_ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field"">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.ProjectType_ID, Model.projecttypes)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

When I do it in this manner, .net doesn't like the Drowpdownlistfor, but I'm unclear how to use these values in a manner that the dropdownlistfor would accept.  What is my mistake?

Edit: Relevent Error for the Dropdownlistfor.

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<ViewModel.ProjectViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' has some invalid arguments c:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test_MVC\Test_MVC\Views\Project\Edit.cshtml
```

Comment: " doesn't like" means what? I doubt .NET said to you "I don't like this". What actually is the exact problem? I'm going to guess it's because Model.projecttypes isn't a list of `SelectListItem`s

Comment: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<ViewModel.ProjectViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' has some invalid arguments c:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test_MVC\Test_MVC\Views\Project\Edit.cshtml 29 14 APTII_MVC"

Comment: Don't have references to your domain model in your view model.  Keep them separate.  Also don't use IQueryable.  IQueryable denotes you are going to run a query in the view.  By the time you get to the view, your DBContext should be disposed.

Comment: update your question with the relevant code,  don't put it in comments.

Comment: I don't understand how I would avoid having a reference to a domain model in a view model.  One has to be populated by the other.

Comment: The 2nd paramater of the `DropDownListFor()` method is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (your `projecttypes` is not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need a `List<SelectListItem>` or `SelectList()`.. so try converting your `projecttypes` object to

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.ProjectType_ID, new SelectList(Model.projecttypes,"ID","Type")`

or edit your viewmodel to

```
public SelectList projecttypes { get; set; }
```

and your controller code to

```
Project.projecttypes = new SelectList(db.APT_ProjectTypes,"ID","Type");
```

just guessing on your value/text field names

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I find the MVC errors to be much harder to parse than the WinForm Errors generally.